# Why I can't iterate over a binary multiple line reading?

Tags: python, binary, iteration

I want to read a Doom WAD with Python. I've saved some random basic WAD from [Doombuilder](http://www.doombuilder.com/), and I'm trying to read it.

```
wad = open("test.wad","rb")
```

If I print readlines():

```
print wad.readlines()
```

Output:

```
['PWAD\x0b\x00\x00\x00U\x01\x00\x00`\xff`\xff\x0e\x01\x01\x00\x07\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\x03\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00STARTAN2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00STARTAN2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00STARTAN2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00STARTAN2\x00\x00\x00\xff\xc0\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\xc0\xff\x00\xff\xc0\xff\xc0\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x02\x00\x00\xc0\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00FLOOR0_1CEIL1_1\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf8\xfe\xf8\xfe\x02\x00\x02\x00\x08\x00\x0c\x00\x10\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\xff\xff\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00MAP01\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\n', '\x00\x00\x00THINGS\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x00LINEDEFSN\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00SIDEDEFS\xc6\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00VERTEXES\xd6\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00SEGS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00SSECTORS\n', '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00NODES\x00\x00\x00\n', '\x01\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x00\x00SECTORS\x00$\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00REJECT\x00\x00%\x01\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00BLOCKMAP']
```

It returns me a list with strings.

Now, if I iterate over it:

```
for i in wad.readlines():
    print i
```

Output:

```
PWAD
```

Just the beginning of it. Why?

I get the same result with previous assingment:

```
x = wad.readlines()
for i in x:
    print i
```

**Here's the link to download the file (Mediafire):**

https://www.mediafire.com/?hvrcmwv1vcwvo29

Comment: Yes, but I need to capture it from the file. If I try to do that same thing from the file, I get just the "PWAD". For example: print ''.join(wad.readlines())

Comment: I get the same result if I try to access some index of it. Just the beginning. For some reason, Python does not read it.

Comment: Yes, I'll find a way to upload it.

Comment: I've added the link to it in the post.

Comment: Binary files don't have "lines".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('test.wad','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print repr(line)


#output 'PWAD\x0b\x00\x00\x00U\x01\x00\x00`\xff`\xff\x0e\x01\x01\x00\x07\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\x03\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00STARTAN2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00STARTAN2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00STARTAN2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00STARTAN2\x00\x00\x00\xff\xc0\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\xc0\xff\x00\xff\xc0\xff\xc0\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x02\x00\x00\xc0\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00FLOOR0_1CEIL1_1\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xf8\xfe\xf8\xfe\x02\x00\x02\x00\x08\x00\x0c\x00\x10\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\xff\xff\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00MAP01\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\n'
'\x00\x00\x00THINGS\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x00LINEDEFSN\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00SIDEDEFS\xc6\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00VERTEXES\xd6\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00SEGS\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00SSECTORS\n'
'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00NODES\x00\x00\x00\n'
'\x01\x00\x00'
```

Comment: I needed to use repr.. Interesting.